# The order value index in boost::multi_index_container

Tags: c++, boost, multi-index

I have a multi_index_container, and index - ordered_unique. I know that my values will be sorted somehow ( by default using less ). What I want is to find the exact ordered index of the value, without using some O(n) algorithm, like std::distance.

```
typedef multi_index_container<
MyStruct,
indexed_by<
    ordered_unique<member< MyStruct, int, &MyStruct::id> >,
    ordered_non_unique<member< MyStruct, int, &MyStruct::salary> >
>
> MyStructsContainer;
```

....

```
MyStructsContainer myStructsContainer;

MyStructsContainer::iterator it1 = myStructsContainer.emplace(MyStruct{ 3, 20 }).first;
MyStructsContainer::iterator it2 = myStructsContainer.emplace(MyStruct{ 1, 100 }).first;
MyStructsContainer::iterator it3 = myStructsContainer.emplace(MyStruct{ 2, 20 }).first;
```

Here it1, it2 and it3 are not RandomAccessIts. Therefore the only way to find the index is:

```
size_t idx = distance(myStructsContainer.begin(), it1); <--- is there any other and smarter way to find the ordered index??
assert(idx == 2);
```

Is there any other approach to do that?

Thanks,
Kalin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to have the insertion order?

In that case, just add a `random_access` index (perhaps making it the default).

You can have O(1) `std::distance` on random-access iterators.

---

**UPDATE** To the comment:

If you want a more efficient order-lookup you can either store the ordinal/rank inside the element, or use a dedicated random access index.

You can easily `rearrange` such an index to match the order you wish:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/952eb7bcb744fdf4)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/random_access_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>

struct MyStruct {
    int id, salary;
};

namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;
typedef boost::multi_index_container<
    MyStruct, bmi::indexed_by<
        bmi::ordered_unique<bmi::tag<struct ById>, bmi::member<MyStruct, int, &MyStruct::id>>,
        bmi::ordered_non_unique<bmi::tag<struct BySalary>, bmi::member<MyStruct, int, &MyStruct::salary>>,
        bmi::random_access<bmi::tag<struct RandomAccess> >
    > > MyStructsContainer;


int main()
{
    MyStructsContainer c;
    auto it3 = c.emplace(MyStruct{ 3, 20  }).first;
    auto it1 = c.emplace(MyStruct{ 1, 100 }).first;
    auto it2 = c.emplace(MyStruct{ 2, 20  }).first;

    auto& ra = c.get<RandomAccess>();

    // reorder RandomAccess index to match the ById
    {
        auto const& idx = c.get<ById>();
        std::vector<boost::reference_wrapper<MyStruct const> > tmp(idx.begin(), idx.end());
        ra.rearrange(tmp.begin());
    }

    // now you can say:
    std::cout << "Index of " << (it1->id) << " is " << (std::distance(ra.begin(), bmi::project<RandomAccess>(c, it1))) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Index of " << (it2->id) << " is " << (std::distance(ra.begin(), bmi::project<RandomAccess>(c, it2))) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Index of " << (it3->id) << " is " << (std::distance(ra.begin(), bmi::project<RandomAccess>(c, it3))) << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
Index of 1 is 0
Index of 2 is 1
Index of 3 is 2
```

The efficience of `std::distance` on this index is `O(1)`

Comment: Nope. I just edited the question in order to make it clean. I need the ordered index.
for it1 it is 2
for it2 it is 1
....

Comment: Thanks, 
This will work for one part of my task. But unfortunately I also want to get the index immediately after emplase.... I may combine both approaches in order to get same optimization, but the solution wont be perfect.

Comment: @KalliMan Sorry. That doesn't exist. Ordered containers are node-based, hence they have no random access. Simple as that.

Comment: Maybe there's an option with [`boost::flat_(multi)set`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost/container/flat_multiset.html). Likely, it doesn't expose the implementation details, but it _might_ give you O(1) distance. In any case, that's not using `multi_index_container`

Comment: Just checked, althought the **[docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.flat_xxx)** don't mention it, the iterators of `flat_set` are indeed random-access: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79576371cd0c071c)**. Just in case you're curious (like me). I'd settle for explicit `int rank;` in `MyStruct`

Comment: But I need it to be multi_set. Also I don't think that it is a good idea to use something which is not well documented. What If one sunny day, boost decide to change it?

Comment: @KalliMan That makes no sense. Why do you think I thought of `flat(_multi)_set` in the first place? It's **defined** as contiguously stored elements (in essence, just a vector). It is well documented, the iterator category is just not explicitly mentioned _on that page_. However, it's random access, since the code compiles. That's _public interface_.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry - I meant "be multi_index".  I need something to be indexed by several indexes. That is Why I cannot use xxxx_set. I really didn't read the flat_set docs. Just read that you mentioned - " althought the docs don't mention it,"....

Comment: Ok. Thanks for clarifying :). I wish you good luck implementing what you need to implement. It's all work in the end. It just differs how much is already implemented for you... And like I said: [I'd settle for explicit int rank; in `MyStruct`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28344031/the-order-value-index-in-boostmulti-index-container/28344318?noredirect=1#comment45035781_28344318). That's a pain to keep consistent, of course. But, checking primes is also a pain. Or character set conversions. And it's all inevitable